# Empty arrays infront of calls and timeouts using class variables?

Tags: php, arrays, class, pdo

I am experiencing the weirdest problems. Please help.

I have a database object that I use to extend my other class objects. In doing so I can easily attach result sets onto class variables and call results statically from anywhere inside the application. Here is my "select" function, which i use to setup the parameters:

```
    public static function select($where="", $bind="", $fields="*", $table="") {
        global $db;
        $object = get_called_class();
            if(empty($table))
                $table = static::$table;

        $sql = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM " . $table;
        if(!empty($where))
            $sql .= " WHERE " . $where;
        $sql .= ";";
        return $db->run($object, $sql, $bind);
}
```

Here is the Database Class Function Run which actually executes the above functions SQL query and parameters and then returns it in an object so I can easily use the object:

```
    public function run($object, $sql, $bind='') {
        $this->sql = trim($sql);
        $this->bind = $this->cleanup($bind);

        try {
            $pdostmt = $this->prepare($this->sql);
            if($pdostmt->execute($this->bind) !== false) {
                switch(strtok($this->sql, ' ')) {
                    case 'DESCRIBE':
                    case 'PRAGMA':
                        return $pdostmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    break;
                    case 'DELETE': 
                    case 'INSERT':
                    case 'UPDATE':
                    case 'REPLACE':
                    case 'TRUNCATE':
                        return $pdostmt->rowCount();
                        break;
                    default:
                        if($object == 'SessionHandler') {
                            if($pdostmt->rowCount() === 1) {
                                return $pdostmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            } else {
                                return $pdostmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if($pdostmt->rowCount() === 1) {
                                $pdostmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, $object); 
                                return $pdostmt->fetch();
                            } else {
                                $pdostmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, $object);
                                return $pdostmt->fetchAll();
                            }

                        }
                        break;
                }

            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $msg = 'Last SQL Query: ' . $this->sql . "\n";
            $msg .= 'SQL Error Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
            Logger::logToFile(__CLASS__, $msg);
            die($msg);
        }
    }
```

These functions work great, when I'm using a single class and pulling the info from another page. But consider the following:

```
    class ACL extends DatabaseObject {
        private $_permissions = array();
        private $_userid = 0;
        private $_user_roles = array();

        public function __construct($userid = 0) {
            global $session;
            if($userid == 0) {
                $this->_userid = $session->userid;
            } else {
                $this->_userid = $userid;   
            }
            $this->get_user_roles($this->_userid);
            $this->get_all_roles();
        }

        public function get_user_roles($userid = 0) {
            $bind = array('userid' => $userid);
            $roles = self::select('userid = :userid', $bind, '*', 'user_roles');
            if(is_object($roles)) {
                $this->_user_roles[] = $roles->roleid;
            } else {
                foreach($roles as $role) {
                    $this->_user_roles[] = $role->roleid;
               }
            }
        }

        public function get_all_roles($format = 'id') {
            $format = strtolower($format);
            echo $this->_userid . '<br />';
        }
    }
```

In the above ACL class, in the constructor of the class, I set the _userid variable of the class equal to the session variable... but when I use `$this->_userid` to call the get_user_roles function, the application crashes? Also, when I print out the `$this->_userid` of the get_all_roles function, three values are returned me instead of one? Also, all the queries I run within this class appends and empty array to the front of the results. The number of empty arrays equal the number of results. Then the last array will hold all the objects?

Please help, I am very confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange indeed. Can you please post any output from the error log, to see where your application is crashing? At first glance I can not really find anything that is obviously wrong, but errors are mostly in the details.

Comment: I think I have found the problem. What was happening? I was returning ACL objects from my queries... I think this is what was causing the hangups and the empty arrays as each ACL object was setting the ACL class variables to its own values. Am i right in making that assumption? What I have done now is return the results as associative arrays and setting the values for the ONE ACL class using the array keys and it seems to be holding up so far.

Comment: Of course. This line is the culprit: PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, $object.

Comment: It basically tells the PDO class to fill that object with the data that is provided. By the way, may I ask why you are passing this object in the first place? I noticed you have an `if` condition on the classname, which isn't really the most flexible thing to do. Why not remove the `$object` parameter, and set it to `$return_format` instead?

Comment: Yup, shortly after realizing what was going on, I altered my DB run function as follows: see below

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above, here is the updated DB Run Method I am using now.

```
    public function run($object, $sql, $bind='', $type='object') {
        $this->sql = trim($sql);
        $this->bind = $this->cleanup($bind);

        try {
            $pdostmt = $this->prepare($this->sql);
            if($pdostmt->execute($this->bind) !== false) {
                switch(strtok($this->sql, ' ')) {
                    case 'DESCRIBE':
                    case 'PRAGMA':
                        return $pdostmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        break;
                    case 'DELETE': 
                    case 'INSERT':
                    case 'UPDATE':
                    case 'REPLACE':
                    case 'TRUNCATE':
                        return $pdostmt->rowCount();
                        break;
                    default:
                        if($type == 'array') {
                            if($pdostmt->rowCount() === 1) {
                                return $pdostmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            } else {
                                return $pdostmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            }
                        } elseif($type == 'object') {
                            if($pdostmt->rowCount() === 1) {
                                $pdostmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, $object); 
                                return $pdostmt->fetch();
                            } else {
                                $pdostmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, $object);
                                return $pdostmt->fetchAll();
                            }

                        }
                        break;
                }

            }
         } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $msg = 'Last SQL Query: ' . $this->sql . "\n";
            $msg .= 'SQL Error Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
            Logger::logToFile(__CLASS__, $msg);
            die($msg);
        }
    }
}
```